# Partition of a family of sets with lower bound on cardinality

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be sets such that $|\cup_{i = 1}^n X_i| = \sum_{i = 1}^n s_i$ and $|X_i| \ge s_i$.

Is there, in general, a partition $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ such that $P_i \subseteq X_i$ and $|P_i| = s_i$ for each $i$?

Comment: "partition" of what? Did you just mean disjoint sets $P_i$?

Comment: @KB presumably $\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, $X_1=\{1,2\}$, $X_2=\{1,3\}$, $X_3=\{1,4\}$; $s_1=s_2=2$, $s_3=0$.

Comment: +1.  And the expansion $X_1=\{1,2,5\}$, $X_2=\{1,3,6\}$, $X_3=\{1,4,7\}$; $s_1=s_2=3$, $s_3=1$ shows the counterexample does not depend on the $0$.

Comment: @Henry, or one can simply add $5$ to $X_3$ in my example and set $s_3=1$.

Comment: Indeed.  And you can shorten your example to $X_1=\{1,2\}$, $X_2=\{1\}$, $X_3=\{3\}$; $s_1=2$, $s_2=1$, $s_3=0$. Or even perhaps $X_1=\{1\}$, $X_2=\{1\}$, $X_3=\{2\}$; $s_1=1$, $s_2=1$, $s_3=0$.